# Formatting float with dot delimiter

Tags: c#, csv, locale

I'm writing a csv converter to convert a text document of transactions into a csv document and I've run into a little problem..

```
    foreach (var transaction in transactions)
    {
        output.Append(
            string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yy},{1},{2},{3},{4:0.##},{5}", 
            transaction.Date, 
            transaction.Payee, 
            transaction.Category,
            transaction.Memo,
            transaction.Outflow,
            transaction.Inflow));
        output.AppendLine();
    }
```

This all works fine, the small issue I have is that the `Outflow` property is a float and my locale uses commas as the decimal delimiter, which is obviously quite a problem in a *CSV* so instead of getting let's say 10.50 it will output 10,50, is there any **easy** way to solve this?

Comment: Saeb's response is valid, but if you choose to leave the commas that is fine since CSV files must use quotation marks around fields that contain embedded quotes.  See section 2.6 of RFC 4180.  http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180

Comment: Using `Invariant` culture is the recommended approach as it signifies a constant (invariant) culture that happens to use periods for decimals and not commas.

Answer (score 5):

You can specify invariant culture which uses `.`:

```
foreach (var transaction in transactions)
{
    output.Append(
        string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yy},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}", 
        transaction.Date, 
        transaction.Payee, 
        transaction.Category,
        transaction.Memo,
        transaction.Outflow.ToString("F2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
        transaction.Inflow));
    output.AppendLine();
}
```

On a side-note, use `decimal` for money not `float`:

`decimal` is base 10 so it can represent fractional currency values like `0.1` exactly, `float` is base 2 and it can't. using `float` will result in strange rounding errors, and comparisons will not work as expected. Consider this:

```
float a = 3.6f, b = 0.1f, expected = 3.7f;
float sum = a + b;
Console.WriteLine(sum == expected); // false
```

This will output false because sum will actually be `3.69999981`

You can read more on the subject from this [C# in Depth excerpt](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/floatingpoint.aspx).

Comment: Why decimal for money?

Answer (score -2):

You can replace the , by . like this:

```
transaction.Outflow.ToString().Replace(',','.');
```

Comment: `Outflow` is a float not a string, so no I can't do that.

Comment: how about converting?